# Send text without html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build some function in JavaScript, that sends text from `textarea` to a `div`.

I want it do the following

> If the user tries to send html source to a textarea, it will show the
>   text, and not the actual html source.

**For example:**

If the user tries to send: `<img src='aa.png'>`

I want to see in the div the text: `<img src='aa.png'>`, and don't want to see the actual image: `aa.png`

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `.innerText` or `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`

`eleme.innerText="<img src='aa.png'>";` where `eleme` is your `div`

DEMO:

```js
document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML="<img src='aa.png'>";
document.getElementById('test2').innerText="<img src='aa.png'>";
document.getElementById('test3').textContent="<img src='aa.png'>";
```

```html
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<div id="test3"></div>
```

You can read more for differences between this three commands and others **[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)**

Comment: Should also be mentioned about `textContent`.